# javascript != not working

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

i have a script that i have written. But the not equal to operator is not working correctly

```
 if((ajax.responseText) != "success"){
                    alert("nice oneagain");
                    alert(ajax.responseText);
                    _(submiit).style.display = "block";
                    _(status).innerHTML = '';
                } else {
                    alert("Complaint escalated");
                    _(status).innerHTML = 'Complaint escalated';
                }
```

here even though the server returns ajax.responseText = success then also it never goes in the else. and only the if part is executed evry time.

Comment: You should not do that that way. The ajax call already includes an argument to pass a function when an error has (or has not, so success) happened. Show me your ajax call and I tell you how to approach it.

Comment: Is `_(submiit).style.display = "block";` meant to say `(submiit)` or is that a typo?

Comment: `ajax.responseText` is probably not `'success'`. How are you verifying that it is?

Comment: @JuanRocamonde that's not necessarily true, the "success" may indicate the success of something specific to this application. It's not necessarily being used for ajax flow control.

Comment: @Dhananjay Gupta you may want to try `console.log(ajax.responseText)`.

Comment: @GershomMaes I suppose you are right :-D

Comment: I love the title for this question. `if(javascript != not working) { return 'Ow. My brain hurts.'; }`

Comment: *When* are you checking `ajax.responseText`? Can we see the call/context in which this test happens?

Comment: The responseText property contains the text result of the call made by the ajax request. So, unless the request is designed to return the literal string "success", the test will never succeed.

Comment: anybody else wonder if this is as obvious as `!==` instead of `!=`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if((ajax.responseText.toString().trim()) != "success"){
                    alert("nice oneagain");
                    alert(ajax.responseText);
                    _(submiit).style.display = "block";
                    _(status).innerHTML = '';
                } else {
                    alert("Complaint escalated");
                    _(status).innerHTML = 'Complaint escalated';
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//instead of checking for responseText check for readystate and status
<script>
if(ajax.readyState==4 && ajax.status ==200){
    alert("nice oneagain");
    alert(ajax.responseText);
    _(submiit).style.display = "block";
    _(status).innerHTML = '';
} else {
    alert("Complaint escalated");
    _(status).innerHTML = 'Complaint escalated';
}
 <script>
```